# How to use “Phoenix.View.render_to_string(…)” with text templates?

Tags: html, elixir, phoenix-framework

Is there an alternative specifically for text templates ?

In a text template I have also elixir variables that I need to replace with values. That is, it's a "soemthing.txt.eex", not simply a ".txt"

Answer (score 0):

Given these templates:

**world.html.eex**:

```
<h1>From a template: Hello <%= String.capitalize(@name) %></h1>
```

**world.txt.eex**:

```
From a template: Hello <%= String.capitalize(@name) %>
```

Here are some results in the shell after calling `render()`, `render_to_string()`, and `render_to_iodata()` on each template:

```
~/phoenix_apps/hello$ iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> Phoenix.View.render_to_iodata(HelloWeb.HelloView, "world.html", conn: %Plug.Conn{}, name: "Wintermute")
["<h1>From a template: Hello ", "Wintermute", "</h1>\n"]

iex(2)> Phoenix.View.render_to_string(HelloWeb.HelloView, "world.html", conn: %Plug.Conn{}, name: "Wintermute")
"<h1>From a template: Hello Wintermute</h1>\n"

iex(3)> Phoenix.View.render(HelloWeb.HelloView, "world.html", conn: %Plug.Conn{}, name: "Wintermute")          
{:safe, ["<h1>From a template: Hello ", "Wintermute", "</h1>\n"]}

iex(4)> 
nil
iex(5)> 
nil

iex(6)> Phoenix.View.render_to_iodata(HelloWeb.HelloView, "world.txt", conn: %Plug.Conn{}, name: "Wintermute") 
"From a template: Hello Wintermute\n"

iex(7)> Phoenix.View.render_to_string(HelloWeb.HelloView, "world.txt", conn: %Plug.Conn{}, name: "Wintermute") 
"From a template: Hello Wintermute\n"

iex(8)> Phoenix.View.render(HelloWeb.HelloView, "world.txt", conn: %Plug.Conn{}, name: "Wintermute")           
"From a template: Hello Wintermute\n"

iex(9)>
```

So, to me it looks like you can use any of the render functions when your file is a `.txt.eex` file.

> How to use Phoenix.View.render_to_string(…) with text - non-html -
>   templates?

I don't know if there is a better way, but this works:

```
defmodule HelloWeb.HelloController do
  use HelloWeb, :controller

  def world(conn, %{"name" => name}) do
    str = Phoenix.View.render_to_string(
              HelloWeb.HelloView, 
              "world.txt", 
              conn: %Plug.Conn{}, 
              name: name)
    text(conn, str)
  end

end
```

**hello_web/templates/hello/world.txt.eex**:

```
From a template: Hello <%= String.capitalize(@name) %>
```

It looks like `text()` replaces any html characters in `str` with *html entities*, e.g. `>` is replaced by `&gt;` so that the browser doesn't render the html.

> Is there an alternative specifically for text templates ?

Another way to accomplish the same thing is to directly use EEx (Embedded Elixir) to do the variable substitutions.  The trick is getting the path to the template file:

**hello/priv/my_text_templates/world.txt:**

```
<%= greeting %> <%= String.capitalize(name) %>!
```

**controller**:

```
defmodule HelloWeb.HelloController do
  use HelloWeb, :controller

  def world(conn, %{"name" => name}) do

    template_path = Path.join([
                      :code.priv_dir(:hello), 
                      "my_text_templates", 
                      "world.txt.eex"])
    str = EEx.eval_file(
            template_path,
            [greeting: "Hello", name: name]
          )

    text(conn, str)
  end

end
```

By the way, `html` and `json` are both strings--a browser just does something different when it sees html in a string.